# How to prompt for password with pycurl? (equivalent to curl -u)

Tags: python, pycurl

Is there a pycurl equivalent to `curl -u username` where I can get Python to prompt for my password?

Comment: You can write Python code to prompt for and read a password.

Answer (score 0):

pycurl does not have a feature where it will prompt for a password.

However, your program can issue the request without credentials and if the response is 401 perform the password prompt using facility such as the [getpass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html) standard library module.